# How can one take input and output it as an anagram with vowels between each consonant?

Tags: c#, algorithm, anagram

I'm relatively new to coding, and I'd like to make a test program which can take an input, and output it as an anagram. But the anagram cannot just be a jumble of letters, it needs to be a comprehensible 'word' of sorts (i.e. if I put in 'dinosaur', I want to get something along the lines of 'nisadoru' in return as opposed to something like 'dsrunsia'). If taking things a step further isn't too much of a stretch, I'm also interested in having the program add an extra letter to the output (i.e. if I put in 'dinosaur', I could receive 'nisadorux').

I'm not looking for a choice of extra letters to be added to the word, I want the letter I choose to be added. The letter, if it matters, is x. So all anagrams would contain an additional x.

I've looked hard, but failed to find any useful help. I haven't any code to go off, but for those of you saying I won't learn from being simply given the code, I prefer to look over a complete piece and deconstruct it or figure out how everything works as opposed to trying to put together various things as a test.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: As I said, nothing yet. I know close to nothing (I can do a little Java, and from that I know only a few basics) and I've no idea where to start. I'd like to see code and learn from it by reading and figuring it out, and learn to incorporate various aspects of it into future code, etc.

Comment: Well, your best bet then would be to start with the basics, string manipulation in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228362(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Split your letters array into two arrays, one having only vowels `[a,e,i,o,u,y]` and the other all the rest, for `dinosaur` you'll receive `[d,n,r,s] - [a,i,o,u]` Then, to make an anagram, throw a random number for the combined number of letters still in the arrays, select a corresponding letter, add it to your anagram in construction, and remove from the arrays. Say your random throws 6 (0-based), first array has length of 4, taking from second array at position 2 (=6-4) -> 'o'. Next random(7) throws 2, taking 'r' from first array, now our anagram has `or` and arrays have `[d,n,s] - [a,i,u]`. And about having vowels interchange with consonants, keep track of which array your letters were waken last consequently, and if there are two consecutive takes from one array, take a letter from the other (at random) instead of taking it from a complete set of remaining letters.

And now, you will have to code this into your program by yourself.

Comment: Y is not a vowel, I tried to remove the Y but it wouldn't let me as i need 6+ changes to fulfill the edit.

Comment: @ZafKhan **WHY** ? #padding#

Comment: I take it back Y is a vowel too. Wow! I learned something today! [Source: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should cover all your needs:

```
static class Program
{
    static readonly char[] Vowels = new []{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
    static readonly Random r = new Random();

    static bool IsVowel(char c) { return Vowels.Contains(c); }
    static bool IsConsonant(char c) { return !IsVowel(c); }

    static string Scramble(string inpt)
    {
        string input = inpt + "x";
        List<char> vowelList = input.Where(IsVowel).ToList();
        List<char> consonantList = input.Where(IsConsonant).ToList();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        bool needVowel = false; // Start with a consonant, if possible.

        while (vowelList.Count > 0 || consonantList.Count > 0)
        {
            IList<char> charList = consonantList;
            if (consonantList.Count == 0 || (needVowel && vowelList.Count > 0))
            {
                charList = vowelList;
            }
            int randomIndex = r.Next(0, charList.Count);
            output.Append(charList.ElementAt(randomIndex));
            charList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            needVowel = !needVowel;
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var s in Enumerable.Repeat("dinosaur", 20).Select(Scramble))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why Random is regenerated everytime? That way a successive call in short time to Scramble() would produce identical result. And I'm not sure why new Random((int) ... ticks...) is any better than just plain new Random() which use the system time anyway

Comment: @Martheen Random is regenerated for each scramble. There WILL be a difference in ticks, no matter how near each execution is since [(From the documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx): "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond." The seed method comes from the [documentation for Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx).

Comment: @Martheen Also, using "ticks" ensures you don't have the problem of frequent initialization. THAT BEING SAID: I agree that Random should be seeded only once for the whole program. But since I don't include the body of the `main`, I figured it would be best to include seeding here.

Comment: Nope. Just tried var data = Enumerable.Repeat("faleticia", 20).Select(Scramble).ToList();
            data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); 

And voila, identical results

Comment: The similar quick call to Ticks also produce identical values. Also, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/3a197913-7d01-415f-a7ff-ba8ff18dae52/ also shows this happen. On trivial function call like this several call can be done on a single tick.

Comment: You do realize the seed method in the documentation is used to demonstrate *identical* result right?